# First order differential equation by the method of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Solve $-yU_x + xU_y= U$, initial conditions $U(x,0)= P(x)$. Characteristic equations: $X_t =-Y$, $Y_t=X$, $U_t=U$. The book says $X(t,s) =F_1(s)\cos t + F_2(s)\sin t$, $Y(t,s)=F_1(s)\sin t  -F_2(s)\cos t$. I can do $U(t,s)$. I can't work out how  $X$ and $Y$  were done.

Comment: @fred. Certainly the book says what are $s$ and $t$. Take accont of those definitions. Without all comes like a bolt from the blue so to speak.

Comment: In polar coordinates $x=\rho\cos(θ)$ ; $y=\rho\sin(θ$) very easily one find $U(\rho,\theta)=e^\theta F(\rho)$ with arbitrary function F. Coming back to Cartesian coordinates and with the condition leads to $U(x,y)=e^{\arctan(y/x)}P(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$.